# Component saving issue in Tridion 2013Sp1

Tags: 2013-sp1

I have a component with 82 child(Dependency) components. I am trying to open the component and modified some attributes in the 4th level of Embedded fields.
While re save the same component it is taking many hours, finally there is no error massage it is throwing.

Comment: When you say there's no error message, do you mean in the CME or have you also checked the Tridion Event Log on the Content Manager server for error messages?

Comment: Yes, I have checked in the Tridion Event logs too. There is no specific logs   fired during the component saving In-Progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good chance that your CM DB stats haven't ran in a while, or page memory is too low.  Make sure you've done the DB maintenance.

Just a thought, if the save transaction spins for hours, perhaps your timeout settings are cranked way up, and the DB is actually spinning endlessly and eventually timing out after the Tridion browser session ends?  So, run your DB maintenance, and also check any logs on the DB side.

Answer (score 2):

82 component links sitting under 4 levels of embedded schema sounds excessive to me - Without knowing the exact error that's occurring it's difficult to know why it's not saving, but I'm not surprised you're having issues trying to use this content model.

This isn't a direct answer to your problem, but I'd seriously consider changing that content model to something more manageable... It sounds to me like you're modelling some kind of data file or structure rather than just content here. Could you revise the schema in some way? Perhaps use a Category and Keywords, Folders or Structure Groups for organisation rather than embedding all those schemas?